# GDELT database analysis for sociological research with SQL language in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gdelt

I'm very new to the whole SQL language and the BigQuery environment, therefore I'm having lots of problems in cleaning data from the GDELT database in order to obtain a tidy dataset that comprises only articles published in UK and spanning from december the 31st 2021 to december the 31st 2023, having refugees and refugee-related topics as themes. My end goal is to then use either Rstudio or Python to analyze the impact of the Russian invasion of Ukraine on the media discourse regarding refugees by considering not only the amount of news regarding this topic, but also the evolution of the average tone of the articles.
Thank you so much for your help!

```
SELECT 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP)) AS PublicationDate,
    DocumentIdentifier AS ArticleURL,
    SourceCommonName AS Source,
    Themes,
    V2Tone,
    SPLIT(V2Tone, ',')[OFFSET(0)] AS ToneScore,
    SPLIT(V2Tone, ',')[OFFSET(1)] AS PositiveScore,
    SPLIT(V2Tone, ',')[OFFSET(2)] AS NegativeScore,
    SPLIT(V2Tone, ',')[OFFSET(3)] AS Polarity,
    SPLIT(V2Tone, ',')[OFFSET(4)] AS ActivityReferenceDensity,
    SPLIT(V2Tone, ',')[OFFSET(5)] AS SelfGroupReferenceDensity,
    SPLIT(V2Tone, ',')[OFFSET(6)] AS WordCount
FROM 
    `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg`
WHERE 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN '2021-12-31' AND '2023-12-31'
    AND LOWER(ActionGeo_CountryCode) = 'it'
    AND (
        Themes LIKE '%REFUGEES%' OR
        Themes LIKE '%SOC_REFUGEECAMP%' OR
        Themes LIKE '%WB_1601_REFUGEE_SUPPORT%' OR
        Themes LIKE '%WB_2665_REFUGEE_RESETTLEMENT%' OR
        Themes LIKE '%WB_2731_REFUGEE_WORKERS%' OR
        Themes LIKE '%WB_2894_REFUGEES_AND_JOBS%'
    )
GROUP BY 
    PublicationDate, ArticleURL, Source, Themes, V2Tone
ORDER BY 
    PublicationDate
```

but i'm finding problems as bigquery tells me it doesnt recognize TIMESTAMP

Comment: Note that `LIKE '%REFUGEES%'` has already covered `LIKE '%WB_2894_REFUGEES_AND_JOBS%'`.